# Google coral developer board not working with waveshare display

Tags: google-coral

Google coral developer board not working with waveshare display , anybody succeeded?
Waveshare display works with rasperry pi good. But it doesn't work with Google coral Dev board running 5.3 mendel version. Looks to me clock from coral is not appropriate.

Does gbm-format field in /etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini make difference? I tried with values, xrgb2101010, rgb565 but coral is failing to boot up.
Do anyone has any solution?, appreciate your answers and valuable time.